# How to deal with connection timeout on ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, arrays, binaryfiles

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that displays some values from the database. One of the features is the possibility to download this values using our legacy file format. While testing it in my own PC (using the development server) it worked fine, but on the server I can't download this file. The download method is basically searching some values from database and creating a binary file (this was created long ago, as a solution for another software). I want to know how to deal with this connection timeout in an elegant way (if there's an elegant way).

My action method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadSignalRecord(long id, long powerPlantID, long generatingUnitID)
        {
            SignalRepository sr = new SignalRepository();
            var file = sr.GetRecordFile(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id);

            return File(file, "binary/RFX", sr.GetRecordName(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id) + ".rfx");
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's not really clear what you'd like to see happen here.  Would you like to extend the DB timeout so the request will be fulfilled?  Would you like to redirect the user to a page indicating a DB timeout has happened?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. First I thought the IIS has timeouted, but it seems to be a problem with mysql, as I read the stack trace paying more attention. Now I want to know how to resolve this, but this is probably the wrong place for it.

Comment: if you can put it in a question with an absolute answer which is programming related, this is indeed the place for it

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public ActionResult DownloadSignalRecord(long id, long powerPlantID, long generatingUnitID)
{
    try
    {
        SignalRepository sr = new SignalRepository();
        var file = sr.GetRecordFile(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Redirect to timeout page
        Redirect("Timeout");
    }

    return File(file, "binary/RFX", sr.GetRecordName(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id) + .rfx");
}
```

Comment: this is not good anyway, you are catching all exceptions and not all of them are related to time outs !

Comment: Yes you would need to filter the exceptions, but as the code stands now, nothing is catching the exceptions.